# LL(1) grammar and indexing operator [ ]

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

I would like to learn how to solve transferring grammar to LL(1). I have following problem:

```
E -> E + E
E -> E * E
E -> E[ E ]
E -> int
E -> id
```

Regarding operators '+' and '*' I know the solution:

```
E -> TA
A -> + TA
A -> epsilon

T -> FB
B -> * FB
B -> epsilon
```

the problem is what to do with indexing operator while in the same time we have to avoid left recursion?

Does anybody know the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple: make it a postfix operator, and apply **right** recursion, that's how the C89 grammar does it.

Comment: Why do you think it is different from the cases you know how to handle?

Comment: Well if I do like other one:
`F -> GC
C -> [ E ]C
C -> epsilon

G -> id
G -> int`
I was thinking that I won't get the same result. But now it looks like a working solution. What do you think?

Comment: @MilošLjumović: I think you've got almost got it, although I don't know if `int[E]` would be valid in your language. I'd go with `F->G C;  F->int; C->[ E ] C; C->epsilon; G->id; G->( E )`

Answer (score 1):

(Elevated from a comment):

Based on the proposed solution for arithmetic operators:

```
E -> T A
A -> + T A
A -> epsilon

T -> F B
B -> * F B
B -> epsilon
```

We can add the almost analogous:

```
F -> G C
F -> int
C -> [ E ] C
C -> epsilon
```

And finish with:

```
G -> id
G -> ( E )
```

The parenthesized expression in the last line wasn't in the original problem, but it seems reasonable to add it. The `F` stanza differs from the other two in that it rejects indexed expressions of integer literals (`3[x]`, for example), although that might be permitted by the target language (it is permitted by `C`, for example) in which case `F -> int` should be replaced with the original `G -> int`.